# Create an equivalent of zmsg with PyZMQ

Tags: zeromq

I'm unarchiving a project that is using CZMQ (thus written in C).
My goal is to add a new subscriber written in Python with PyZMQ (v25.1.0). To do so, I need to interact with the registry and publishers written with CZMQ.

I don't know if it's the best way to do it, but the existing subscriber registers to the registry by using the following code (not full):

```
zmsg_t *message = zmsg_new();
uint32_t  tag = 0x12345678;
zframe_t *tag_frame = zframe_new(&tag, sizeof(tag));
zframe_t *type_frame = zframe_new(&type, sizeof(self->type));
...
zmsg_append(message, &tag_frame);
zmsg_append(message, &type_frame);
...
zsock_send(req_socket, "4m", 1, message);
```

Now I'm trying to format the same registration message with PyZMQ but the API (https://pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/zmq.html) does not have the same capabilities.

Any idea how to do that in Python?

I've tried the following code (even though zmq.Message is not described in the API):

```
message = zmq.Message()
tag = 0x12345678
type_value = 1
tag_frame = zmq.Frame(tag.to_bytes(4, byteorder='big'))
type_frame = zmq.Frame(type_value.to_bytes(4, byteorder='big'))
message.append(tag_frame)
message.append(type_frame)
```

but zmq.Message does not have any append method.

I've also not found how to send a 'picture' message.

Comment: I suspect the C API is using ZeroMQ multi-part messages. Try `send_multipart`.

Comment: Gaah, this is one of the slight annoyances of ZeroMQ. There's a perfectly good standard API. Then, that gets dressed up in other things like CZMQ, which does "other things" (such as frames). For a library that rightfully boast tremendous heterogeneity, having higher level bindings that hide how they're using ZMQ and not replicating them in every single language rather spoils the point!

Comment: With the picture being "4m" it appears that what zsock_send is doing under the hood is converting the binary data to text. Looks like this is some sort of primitive data serialisation facility.

Comment: How is it going? One way of understanding what is required could be to run the original C version, and use Wireshark to intercept the communications. Wireshark has a ZeroMQ dissector, so it would show you what messages were being passed from one machine to another and back. That way, you'd effectively get a specification for the messages you'd have to send in Python to recreate it. Does that sound achieveable?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I was actually monitoring the number of answers and didn't see the comments.
Anyway, I'm definitely going to try the `send_multipart`. I've also analyzed the communication with Wireshark but didn't know about the ZeroMQ dissector, which will help in this task. I actually already tried to reproduce the CZMQ output with PyZMQ but was not certain about the exact formatting as ZMQ adds some fields for number of bytes and some sort of checksum.
I'll keep you posted.